# What can I do to stop the Play / Pause button from opening iTunes?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, media-keys

In Snow Leopard the Play / Pause media button (on the <kbd>F8</kbd> key) opens up iTunes. How can I disable that? Preferably keeping the old Leopard behaviour, so I can use it to control other media applications (e.g. Spotify).

Comment: Apple forum thread about the issue: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10075555 — no solution though. (Even if the page strangely claims "This question is answered")

Comment: Another unclosed thread on this: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=757430

Comment: This one is loaded with good solutions: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2122639&start=30&tstart=0

Comment: This is FIXED in Lion.

Comment: @AugustLilleaas It is not fixed in Lion!

Comment: Ugh, I can't add an answer due to lack of rep -- but I found a great patch for the rcd (Remote Control Daemon) that fixes this completely -- http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch -- code on github here: https://github.com/thebitguru/play-button-itunes-patch

Comment: This is fixed in Mountain Lion and Mavericks.

Comment: @Dag Høidahl This is NOT fixed in mountain lion & mavericks. The media keys are bound to the last active media application. Ie. you are using spotify with the keys and it works fine. You pause spotify, play a video in VLC, then close VLC. Now the media keys are still bound to VLC because it's the last active app. However, you have closed VLC so the binding is lost. Pressing the play key now opens itunes again instead of controlling spotify.

Comment: @Maurice I hadn't noticed that behaviour when closing apps, just that I can control e.g. Spotify without iTunes opening. I'd say the problem is still a little broken, but mostly fixed.

Comment: @olly – Please consider marking http://superuser.com/a/827710/491679 the best answer. It was posted much later, but it's seems to be exactly what most users reading this will need.

Comment: El Captain
`cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS;
sudo mv iTunes iTunesX;
sudo chmod uog+x iTunesX`

Comment: It's mind boggling how this is still a problem 8 WHOLE YEARS LATER!! This is proof that Apple doesn't actually listen to users. They just force their stuff onto you, like it or not. And each OS update just breaks again all tricks to disable effing iTunes!

Comment: (I don't have enough rep to write an answer) An easy solution - If you don't use iTunes at all like me, simply right click, disable all permissions for "everyone".

Comment: Dear visitors from the future:
`launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

a better temporary fix is to start quicktime and just have it running(not playing a movie) in the background. It uses less ram/cpu than iTunes.

Comment: Indeed, this is a slightly better work-around

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it is the easiest and least problematic of the solutions.

Comment: This does not appear to work on Lion, iTunes still opens for me, regardless of if Quicktime is open or not.

Comment: See answer from @bernk from 17-Oct-2014 that has a simple fix that survives new versions of the operating system and is simple and correct.

Comment: here's a similar fix, if you happen to use google chrome and have it always opened: install google music app. or any chrome extension that will "hijack" the media keys, such as sway or streamkey. only thing is they [might bring some problems](http://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-google-music-media-keys/) of their own. now [I'm wondering how to fix this once and for all](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283395/get-media-keys-to-always-play-latest-media-run).

Comment: This is just sad :(

Comment: This was working for me up until Mojave (I skipped High Sierra). Now even when I have quicktime and amazon music open, iTunes still opens every time.

Answer (score 164):

**Update: There is a GUI available that performs the below steps, at [the official website](http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch).**

Fixing this is very simple. While the installation process does involve using Mac Terminal, you do not need any knowledge of it. I have included images to make it easier! Just follow 6 simple instructions below and you are done!

1. [Download this zip file](https://github.com/thebitguru/play-button-itunes-patch/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file
3. Run the Patch.command file (Double Click It)
4. It will open mac terminal. It will most likely prompt you to enter your password. Type your password and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. It should look similar to the image below:

   [image: step 4]
5. At the bottom it will say "Everything is ready. Would you like to create a backup and apply the patch (y/N)". Type <kbd>y</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It should look similar to the image below:

   [image: Step 5]
6. You are done! It should output some text and say `[Process Complete]` at the bottom. You can then close the mac terminal window. The process completing successfully should look similar to the image below:

   [image: Step 6]

### Uninstall

If you want to remove this patch, simply run the Patch.command script again.

[Here is the github repository](https://github.com/thebitguru/play-button-itunes-patch) Thanks to thebitguru for this script.

Comment: Works perfectly in snow leopard. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: And runs great on Lion too!

Comment: Binary moved here: http://nomitsu.com/contents/MMFix.dmg
Works great on 10.7.3 Lion!

Comment: Still works in Mavericks!

Comment: Is it known if this works on Mavericks or Yosemite?

Comment: Would love a way to now bind this to launch Spotify

Comment: Works on Yosemite

Comment: I've noticed that I've had to uninstall and re-install it after some updates or when the OS updates, but this script has been a real trooper. Big fan.

Comment: It is now updated, so you actually open the `package` folder, and run the `Play Button iTunes Patch.app`, press `patch` and type your password twice. It even takes a backup which you can restore from. Great stuff!

Comment: Excellent! Looks like the devs are maintaining the script. I had to go to the Github page and download. Works just fine on Yosemite.

Comment: in Yosemite, iTunes is still being opened. Didn't work for me.

Comment: There's a new version of this with a gui, and it works on OS X 10.10. Just download and run the dmg at http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch.

Comment: This stopped working for El Capitan.

Comment: @w00t: On El Capitan you need to disable SIP before applying the patch: http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch

Answer (score 133):

The real solution: Open Terminal, paste in the following line, and hit enter. You're done. To undo, change `unload` to `load` in the same line.

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

Comment: This worked for well for me with iTunes 12 and Yosemite.

Comment: This works on El Capitan, but it doesn't forward the play button event to the actively playing application

Comment: This is the best solution and works on El Capitan!

Comment: This will completely disable the remote control device (rcd), if I am not mistaken. Which will not allow you to use your mac remote control, if you have that.

Comment: @w00t I haven't found that to be the case on my machine. Works with OS X 10.11.3, iTunes 12.3.2.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore on MacOs Sierra... Too bad I liked having a simple command to do that.

Comment: I use MacOs Sierra 10.12.1 and it works. Perhaps you need to be root?

Comment: Did not work in Sierra. Got following error: /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist: Could not find specified service

Comment: @NitroG42 Just realized the unload just removes it from starting on boot time.  If you don't want to restart, you can kill it the running rcd process with  `launchctl stop com.apple.rcd` or a direct `kill -9 <rcd pid>`

Comment: Well it worked now because app like Spotify were updated to comply with the new media key system, but at the time I wrote, nothing was working, and you killing the rc daemon wouldn't change anything.
If you are interested in how it works to catch those events in app, look here : https://github.com/jguice/mac-bt-headset-fix/tree/sierra

Comment: On Sierra this requires SIP to be disabled.

Comment: It works for me on Sierra. Thank you! This is an awesome answer...

Comment: This no longer works for me since i upgraded to Mojave.

Comment: Stop Music.app from opening on 10.15.4.  However, I still cannot control Amazon Music instead, except when it is in focus, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: This is a great answer - worked as a charm on Catalina. Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

For controlling Spotify, use Shift + Option + Play button. iTunes does not react to this combination, but Spotify does.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, +1. However, this is starting to get a bit unwieldy as I like to have the "standard function keys" option on, i.e. I need to press 4 keys: Fn + Shift + Option + Play :P

Comment: This tip also works for controlling Rdio.

Comment: ++ Nice simple workaround. Too bad it isn't more intuitive.

Comment: kinda annoying having to use modifier keys, but hey, if it means i don't have to open something else up or keep closing itunes then I'm happy

Comment: In Mountain Lion (at least version 10.8.3), this behaviour seems to be fixed. When Spotify is open, iTunes does not open anymore.

Comment: This seems to not work on Mavericks

Comment: I haven't needed to use this trick since Mountain Lion. The Play/Pause button does not open iTunes anymore if Spotify is open.

Answer (score 19):

andrew px and dmonner wrote an excellent workaround here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2122639&start=30&tstart=0

It uses a python script and some renaming to prevent iTunes from opening when applications of your choice are already open:

Open a Terminal and type the following

```
cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS
sudo mv iTunes iTunesX 
sudo curl https://web.archive.org/web/20130327115441if_/http://www.cs.umd.edu/~dmonner/iTunes -O
sudo chmod uog+x iTunes
```

From [https://web.archive.org/web/20130327115441if_/http://www.cs.umd.edu/~dmonner/iTunes](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Edmonner/iTunes)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, subprocess

launch = True
blocker = ""

apps = ["Spotify", "Songbird"]

ps = subprocess.Popen("/bin/ps -x", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in ps.stdout.read().split("\n"):
    for app in apps:
        if app in line:
            launch = False
            blocker = app

ps.stdout.close()

if launch :
    os.spawnvp(os.P_WAIT, '/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesX', sys.argv)
else :
    print "Not launching iTunes while %s is running." % blocker
```

Add whatever application you need to the list `apps = ["Spotify", "Songbird", "your app here"]`

Comment: I've done this in the past, but Apple Update likes to overwrite it.

This last time I tried making the file system and userimmutable, we'll see if Apple Update respects that flag. I cant really test it until a new update is available, but if anyone else wants to try it:
 sudo chflags uchg /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
 sudo chflags schg /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes


If you want to disable that (e.g to actually update):

 sudo chflags nuchg /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
 sudo chflags noschg /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes

Comment: Upvote this, zomg!

Comment: This is fantastic.

Answer (score 6):

Renaming iTunes only works until OS X finds it again. I deleted it from Applications and a couple of minutes later it was found on my backup disk and the problem returned. Deleted it from there to, no more problems. Don't forget to emty the Trash, or it will probably be found there...

So, deleting all copies works fine for me. My music is flac so I have no use for it anyway.

Comment: I'd hope there was some solution also for those of us who use iTunes (too), and don't want to delete it...

Answer (score 5):

**I have a 'workaround':**

- Quit iTunes
- Locate iTunes.app in Finder (In Finder: Menu › Go › Applications...)
- Ctrl-click on the iTunes.app-file and select 'Compress "iTunes.app"' (for backup)
- Ctrl-click on the iTunes.app-file and select 'Show Package Contents'
- Locate the file '**Info.plist**' inside the folder 'Contents'
- Ctrl-click 'Info-plist' and select 'Open with..' and select 'TextEdit' (or your favourite text-editor. Not Word tho.)
- Near the bottom of the file locate the following segment:

  ```
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.iTunes</string>
  ```
- Change the last 's' in the word 'iTunes' to 'z', like so:

  ```
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.iTunez</string>
  ```
- Save the file
- IMPORTANT: Drag the file 'iTunes.app' out of the Applications-folder and on to the Desktop
- Drag the file 'iTunes.app' back into the Applications folder
- (You should probably disable the iTunesHelper. This can be done by going to System Preferences › Accounts › (Your account) › Login Items and remove the 'iTunesHelper'.)
- Log out and log in

**I hope this works. It works for me!**

Comment: It works but it seems to damage the iTunes Code Signing Certificate which is ok but everytime you open up iTunes (on a Mac) you'll be asked if the application is allowed to make outgoing connections.

Comment: Can't remove the iTunes.app out of Applications... it says "“iTunes” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by Mac OS X."

Answer (score 3):

For Snow leopard users:
Ok i didnt find an answer for this problem, but i tried to work my way around(for people who wants to watch videos on VLC and pause it with the apple remote/keyboard and itunes keep opening)
option 1:
open itunes and let it run but click on itunes store and hide itunes or minimize it. continue with watching videos on VLC and music won't play.

option 2:
Use Front Row to watch all your videos. To do so install PERIAN for quicktime(which allows you to play all formats in quicktime) and put all your movies in your "movies" folder. Enjoy watching movies through front row.

option 3:(this one worked partially. )
Rename itunes in applications folder to "itunes_off". In order to do this you might need to make your user privileges to" read and write". right click on itunes and click on "get info" then go in privileges and click on little lock icon, enter your password and then change your user setting to "read and write". After this rename itunes to something else. But this solution didnt work correctly for me. it stopped opening itunes for a while but when i restarted my mac it started opening it again.
Try if this works for anybody.
And keep me posted.

Comment: Out of all options presented so far, your **option 1** seems like an ok work-around; +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

I only used iTunes and Spotify.

**I've found the following low-tech solution works:**

**1.** Open iTunes and select one of the folders under "library" that has no content - I never have any "ringtones" for instance; You can also create an empty playlist and select this.

**2.** Leave iTunes open, but select "Hide iTunes" in the "Itunes" menu.

The results is although iTunes is open it doesn't have any content to play and so when I hit the 'play' button all I hear is music from Spotify.

Comment: Creating a new empty playlist works as well.  Just make sure this playlist is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how many other applications this will work with, but it certainly works with Spotify: if it's already open, pressing option while using the media keys will not open iTunes, and will control Spotify in the background.

Comment: Just tried this on my Macbook (OS X 10.6.3) with Spotify & iTunes. iTunes *did* keep opening despite pressing alt/option along with the media keys. :/

Comment: But if you add shift it works that way! See http://superuser.com/questions/31925/stop-play-pause-button-opening-itunes-in-snow-leopard/107466#107466

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix that I think is better than these... download functionflip at http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/ and check two boxes: "F8: Play/pause" and "Start FunctionFlip at Login."  Then go to Ecoute or Spotify or whatever you're using, and set the keyboard shortcut for play/pause to F8 by pressing the play/pause key.  Now it'll work just as you want it to, and you will still be able to use it with itunes if you hold down the function (fn) key while you press it.

Works great for me!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the name of iTunes.app, try changing the name of

```
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
```

to, for example

```
iTunes_
```

This prevents the iTunes.app from working when you double click on it, but at least it saves you from the respawning of iTunes when you press play/pause. If you want to use iTunes.app just rename the file back to "iTunes"

Comment: Works perfectly, even on Sierra :)

Comment: On El Capitan this doesn't work:
```foo:MacOS root# pwd
/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS
foo:MacOS root# mv iTunes iTunes_
mv: rename iTunes to iTunes_: Operation not permitted```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, though slightly hacky. Basically run iTunes, but select 'Applications' or 'Radio' from the side menu.

That way, when you press the play buttons, there is nothing to play in iTunes so it doesn't do anything, but it works in the application you want to control.

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch available at http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch that will disable opening iTunes when pressing the Play/Pause multimedia key. You have to unzip the file you download from the 'Play Button iTunes Patch 0.7' and run the 'Patch.command' program in the PlayButtonItunesPatch directory.

I have tested it on Snow Leopard (Mac OSX 10.6) and it works flawlessly. Play/Pause continues to work on open programs but will no longer open up iTunes. If you test it please leave feedback in the comments, whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

The patches provided here generally don't work on more recent versions of Mac OS X like Mountain Lion.  Drawing more attention to @trisweb's answer in a comment:

> Latest Mountain Lion patch here: thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch /
>   github: github.com/thebitguru/play-button-itunes-patch

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-in-progress solution.. I mainly use XMBC and Hulu so can live without iTunes until there is a real solution:

1. Delete iTunes from Applications
2. Delete Front Row from Applications
3. Empty your trash can

**After these steps Hulu and XMBC are usable via the remote again!** The only issue is that the Menu Key on the Remote still opens Front Row

=====

Personally I am considering using Win7 on my HTPC Mac Mini. Every app I use on the Mac has a Windows counterpart. It looks like this open source software will let the IR work in Boot Camp: http://www.eventghost.org/

Comment: As with http://superuser.com/questions/31925/stop-play-pause-button-opening-itunes-in-snow-leopard/33046#33046, a very limited number of people can take this advice. Many of us want to use iTunes (too), or need it for e.g. iPhone syncing.

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences, under the Keyboard pane, on the Keyboard tab, enable "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".  Be sure to read the note about getting that functionality back by holding the Fn key.

Assign your Function-keys to various functions either in the Keyboard Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard pane, given application, or other preference pane (Exposé, etc).

Use an application like Quicksilver or Butler to assign actions, applications, and/or AppleScripts to various key shortcuts of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem (I only use spotify and iTunes so it probably wasn't as difficult) using an applescript that play/pauses spotify and Quicksilver. It won't work with a remote but If you just want to be able to quickly play/pause spotify without making itunes open and play etc it works like a treat.

This is the applescript if you're interested:

```
tell application "Spotify" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Spotify"
        click menu item 1 of menu 1 of menu bar item 5 of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a sort of low tech thingy that at least prevents iTunes to auto start. I renamed the iTunes.app using:

```
sudo mv /Applications/iTunes.app /Applications/iTunesX.app
```

This stops iTunes from autostarting but if you have it started you're still able to use media controls for it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent Lifehacker article that pointed how to disable it:

- [Free Your Mac's Media Keys from iTunes, No Manual Hacking Required](http://lifehacker.com/5651055/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-no-manual-hacking-required)

Answer (score 0):

this solution is permanent and fool-proof. Go to your login items and take the iTunes Helper out of the login items, then go to Activity monitor (found in the Utilities folder under Applications) and quit out of iTunes Helper. The keys keep working, but iTunes Helper does not reopen and hitting play no longer opens iTunes.

Comment: Wrong. iTunes Helper launches iTunes when e.g. an iPhone is connected. I just `killed` the `iTunesHelper` process and pressed *Play*, iTunes still launched.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed now with iTunes 10.2 (released the same day the iPad 2 was presented). Now I can use Spotify without having to open an idle instance of Quicktime!

Comment: I just updated to 10.2.1 and the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

WORKING FIX, simplest and most effective solution (per mritunjai at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2570254?start=75&tstart=0):

1. Open Terminal
2. Enter (these are two separate commands)

   ```
   launchctl stop com.apple.rcd
   launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
   ```

Comment: is this so different from [the second most voted answer here](https://superuser.com/a/827710/28411) so you had to add an answer rather than simply putting a comment there?

Comment: Can this duplicated answer be hidden and closed?

Answer (score 0):

I realize the OP originally asked about Snow Leopard, but it seems that at least for Spotify, this problem no longer exists on High Sierra -- the remote control buttons work just fine with Spotify and iTunes is no longer started as a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

a solution that worked for me for **Mojave** was to remove the execution bit from iTunes:

`sudo chmod -x /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes`

and optionally add the media player in question under

`Preferences -> Security & privacy -> Accessibility`

Answer (score 0):

The software *[Mac Media Key Forwarder](http://milgra.com/mac-media-key-forwarder.html)* provides a user-friendly approach to prioritizing Spotify for your media keys. It runs in the background and gives you a few simple settings in the Mac menu bar. It just works.

[image]

**Download and installation**

It can be downloaded and installed directly from [the homepage](http://milgra.com/mac-media-key-forwarder.html), or by using e.g. Homebrew:

```
brew cask install macmediakeyforwarder
```

**Notes**

- It is compatible with macOS Catalina.
- The software was previously known as *High Sierra Media Key Enabler*.
- Ensure the application is given [sufficient privileges](https://github.com/milgra/macmediakeyforwarder) in *Security & Privacy* in the *System Preferences*.
- I am not affiliated with the developer(s), I am just a satisfied user.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution: rename itunes.app!

1. Get read/write permissions on itunes
   select the app and press ctrl+i
   click the small lock icon in the bottom left corner
   enter your password
   now set "everyone" to read write
   close the info window
2. Now you can rename the itunes.app

No more itunes popup open all the time!