# How do I parameter the Remote Control on an iMac?

Tags: software-rec, remote-control

I just installed Snow Leopard X.6 on my iMac 24", and now the remote control is acting strangely.
Before, it only worked on video software (VLC, DVD player, etc...), at least in priority.
Now, when I watch a movie with VLC, I pause it, it launches iTunes, I replay it, it plays music in iTunes.
I already disabled all remote controls in iTunes, and "cleaned" the one already registered,
but I still have the same problem.
I would like to know if there is an "apple way" to parameter the remote control, and chose for witch software it is actually active, or maybe another program?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not really will help you, but it should. Why don't you ask this question on Appple support forum?
http://discussions.apple.com/index.jspa

Comment: You're right, it might have been more helpfull... But I just like superuser so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [discussion on the apple board](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2122639&tstart=0) for that topic, which links a [temporary solution on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/31925/stop-play-pause-button-opening-itunes-in-snow-leopard).

Unfortunately, there seems to be no real solution from apple. In the other superuser question, there are some more links out to the apple discussion forums with some hacks that fix this problem.

There is [a free app](http://www.iospirit.com/labs/candelair/) which provides an alternate IR driver which can be used to fix this rather elegantly.