# Mac keyboard shortcut to rm file

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permanently deleting files on Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/10676/permanently-deleting-files-on-mac-os)

What's the Mac keyboard shortcut to rm a file? I know command + delete sends it to trash, but I want to permanently delete it, say with command + fn + delete.

UPDATE: It doesn't look like there is one. So, I want to create a [service with Automator](https://superuser.com/questions/45740/fast-user-switching-apple-menu/46308#46308) and then assign a keyboard shortcut to it from System Preferences.

I can get to Automator -> Service -> Service receives selected files or folders in Finder.app, but how do I write the script that then runs `rm -rf #{file/folder name}`?

Comment: maybe with shift? at least that's the way you have to do it on other OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your edit requesting Automator help:

Use the *Run Shell Script* action, *Pass input as arguments* and the following script:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    rm -rf "$f"
done
```

---

You can assign a keyboard shortcut via *Application Menu*, *Services*, *Services Preferences*. It's a bit difficult to assign backspace/"delete" to a keyboard shortcut (see comments on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/222006/mac-osx-preview-disable-the-command-backspace-move-to-trash-keyboard-shortcut/222053#222053)) though.

You can alternatively create an *application* in Automator, and add a reference to the Finder toolbar (applications can be dragged there).

---

Assigning a keyboard shortcut using *delete* (*backspace*) or *forward delete*:

1. Define a simple keyboard shortcut for the service without *delete* (e.g. `Cmd-Ctrl-Opt-G`) using System Preferences. Quit System Preferences.
2. Open `~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist` using `Property List Editor` and copy the key for the service. It's within `NSServicesStatus` and looks something like `(null) - Service Name - runWorkflowAsService`. Quit Property List Editor.
3. Open Terminal and enter the following command (use the line you copied earlier between the quotes and double-quotes):

   `defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add '"(null) - Service Name - runWorkflowAsService"' '{ "key_equivalent" = "@\U0008"; }'`
4. Open *Application Menu* » *Services* » *Service Preferences*, and toggle your service.
5. Enjoy your new key combination.

In the command line, @ is Cmd, ^ is Ctrl, $ is Shift, and ~ is Option. Mix and match these modifiers to your preferences. `\U0008` is *delete* (*backspace*), `\U007F` is *forward delete*.

[image]

Comment: Regarding assigning a keyboard shortcut using *delete*: `defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add '(null) - My Service Name - runWorkflowAsService' '{ "key_equivalent" = "@\U0008"; }'` *should* work, but `(null)` (indicating a standalone service, not part of an application) is apparently not a valid key for `defaults`: *defaults[56054:903] Could not parse [the key]*

Comment: Thanks! I am doing this only for Finder, so it shows up in `com.apple.finder.plist`. Perhaps I'll change it to work for _All Applications_. What's the purpose of increasing the number value for `NSServicesUserDirectoryModDate`? I thinks `$` is Shift. What's fn?

Comment: @Matt Even if your service is only applicable to Finder, it's key combination is stored in `pbs.plist`. `Fn` is not a modifier key. If you want to go on with `Fn-Cmd-Delete` or similar, this is the exactly same thing as `Cmd-Forward Delete`. `Delete`'s code is `\U0008` above, I don't know the key code for forward delete. If you find it out, just put it into the command line of step 3 and it should work.

Comment: @Matt You could try `@\U007F` for `Cmd-Forward Delete`, `0x7F` is the ASCII key code for `DEL`.

Comment: Sorry, another edit is needed :-) as the following seems to work: `defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add '"(null) - My Service Name - runWorkflowAsService"' '{ "key_equivalent" = "@\U0008"; }'` (Hence: double quotes within the single quotes. Not sure why I suddenly tried that!)

Comment: @Arjan Good to know. I'm done for the night (central european time), will do that tomorrow. Not sure it's that much of an improvement here though, I think it didn't work for me without editing the timestamp.

Comment: I tested it with [my Open Super User example](http://superuser.com/questions/72468/how-can-i-program-the-function-keys-on-my-macbook/97813#97813). After using Terminal, each running program needs to be made aware of changes. Stopping System Preferences, opening it again and disabling and re-enabling the service did the trick. Maybe there's some command line option for that too. Unfortunately, for Delete the Keyboard section only shows "⌘", not "⌘⌫" in the Shortcuts... :-(

Comment: (And `$` is Shift.)

Comment: @Matt I edited to post after I verified that `\U007F` is indeed *forward delete* (i.e. `Fn+Delete`). You specifically want to use `"@\U007F"` for `Cmd-Fn-Delete`.

Answer (score 1):

See [this MacGeekery post](http://www.macgeekery.com/gspot/2007-03/getting_immediate_delete_functionality).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the keyboard shortcut is or even if it exists but you can run an applescript that will permanently delete files.  Here's a link with instructions
http://macphobia.com/deleting-an-item-windows-and-mac.macphobia

Answer (score 0):

```
set txt to ""
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (get selection)
        set txt to txt & quoted form of POSIX path of (f as text) & " "
    end repeat
end tell
set cmd to "rm -rf " & txt
display dialog cmd & "?"
do shell script cmd
```

You can use [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) (or for example [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)) to assign a shortcut that's only available in Finder.