# Shift-Delete equivalent in OS X

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permanently deleting files on Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/10676/permanently-deleting-files-on-mac-os)

In OS X, is there a way to delete a file and bypass Trash? I want an equivalent shortcut for Shift-Delete in Windows.

Comment: Another related question at Ask Different: [How to remap delete and shift+delete keys to delete and permanently delete a file in Mac OS X Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45655/how-to-remap-delete-and-shiftdelete-keys-to-delete-and-permanently-delete-a-fil). The easiest way to delete files permanently would probably be to type `rm -r` in a shell and paste or drag the files as arguments. `srm -rs` would delete them securely.

Comment: Here is my solution to it: http://daemonconstruction.blogspot.in/2013/01/mac-os-x-shift-delete.html

Answer (score 8):

There is no equivalent key combination on OS X. You can delete files only passing through the Trash with the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> and empty trash using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>.

Other solutions involve Automator I guess, but I have no other suggestions about that. All I can say is run such a command on the terminal to batch the process:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Comment: This answer is out of date now, and possibly even when it was posted. Option + Command + Delete deletes a file while skipping the Trash.